# Eclipse format bracket switch and space

Tags: java

i'm searching in eclipse's formatting option but i cannot find anything relative to what i want.
Basically i want turn this

```
switch (event)
        {
        case "32114-05.html":
            st.startQuest();
            break;
        case "32114-08.html":
```

into this

```
   switch(event)
   {
      case "32114-05.html":
      {
          st.startQuest();
          break;
      }
      case "32114-08.html":
```

But i cannot find the option.

Comment: that's a very individual formattig. you have to write you own code formatter. In eclipse look for "formatter"..